# Building the Custom Connector's Actions Responses by Importing sample JSON is not working

Tags: json, powerapps, power-automate, power-platform, power-automate-custom-connector

I am creating a Custom Connector inside Power Automate and Power Apps, and inside the Actions section, i am building the responses objects by importing a sample JSON as follow:-

[image]

Here is the JSON sample i applied:-

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "payments": [
        {
          "id": 15,
          "evidenceId": 1,
          "purpose": "INVOICE",
          "reference": "sdfaasdfasdf",
          "beneficiary": {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "A R C Car Wash",
            "email": "ja@bra.com",
            "phone": "",
            "trusted": false,
            "paymentDetails": [
              {
                "id": null,
                "currency": null,
                "sortCode": "30-30-30",
                "accountNumber": "35353535",
                "iban": null,
                "bic": null,
                "abartn": null,
                "ifscCode": null,
                "type": "SC",
                "address": null
              }
            ],
            "externalId": "5902be62-72f9-4a04-9aa7-cb112de665ab",
            "taxResidency": null,
            "nationalId": null,
            "digitalId": null,
            "registrationId": null,
            "vatId": null,
            "lei": null,
            "type": "ORGANISATION"
          },
          "dueDate": null,
          "amountToPay": 12,
          "amountDue": 89,
          "currency": "GBP",
          "payerDetailsResponse": {
            "id": 1,
            "institutionId": "modelo-sandbox",
            "institutionName": "Modelo Sandbox",
            "bulkAvailable": true,
            "maxBulkPayments": 50,
            "minBulkPayments": 2,
            "iban": null,
            "bic": null,
            "sortCode": "700001",
            "accountNumber": "70000001",
            "balance": -1234500801.09,
            "currency": "GBP"
          },
          "state": "COMPLETED",
          "initiationDate": "2022-02-04T14:06:23",
          "statusLastChanged": "2022-02-04T14:08:05",
          "statusLastChecked": "2022-02-04T14:08:05"
        },
        {
          "id": 14,
          "evidenceId": 1,
          "purpose": "INVOICE",
          "reference": "asdfasqwerqwer",
          "beneficiary": {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "A R C Car Wash",
            "email": "ja@bra.com",
            "phone": "",
            "trusted": false,
            "paymentDetails": [
              {
                "id": null,
                "currency": null,
                "sortCode": "30-30-30",
                "accountNumber": "35353535",
                "iban": null,
                "bic": null,
                "abartn": null,
                "ifscCode": null,
                "type": "SC",
                "address": null
              }
            ],
            "externalId": "5902be62-72f9-4a04-9aa7-cb112de665ab",
            "taxResidency": null,
            "nationalId": null,
            "digitalId": null,
            "registrationId": null,
            "vatId": null,
            "lei": null,
            "type": "ORGANISATION"
          },
          "dueDate": null,
          "amountToPay": 1,
          "amountDue": 89,
          "currency": "GBP",
          "payerDetailsResponse": {
            "id": 1,
            "institutionId": "modelo-sandbox",
            "institutionName": "Modelo Sandbox",
            "bulkAvailable": true,
            "maxBulkPayments": 50,
            "minBulkPayments": 2,
            "iban": null,
            "bic": null,
            "sortCode": "700001",
            "accountNumber": "70000001",
            "balance": -1234500801.09,
            "currency": "GBP"
          },
          "state": "COMPLETED",
          "initiationDate": "2022-02-04T11:26:30",
          "statusLastChanged": "2022-02-04T11:27:47",
          "statusLastChecked": "2022-02-04T11:27:47"
        },
        {
          "id": 13,
          "evidenceId": 1,
          "purpose": "INVOICE",
          "reference": "petyavasyakatya",
          "beneficiary": {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "A R C Car Wash",
            "email": "ja@bra.com",
            "phone": "",
            "trusted": false,
            "paymentDetails": [
              {
                "id": null,
                "currency": null,
                "sortCode": "30-30-30",
                "accountNumber": "35353535",
                "iban": null,
                "bic": null,
                "abartn": null,
                "ifscCode": null,
                "type": "SC",
                "address": null
              }
            ],
            "externalId": "5902be62-72f9-4a04-9aa7-cb112de665ab",
            "taxResidency": null,
            "nationalId": null,
            "digitalId": null,
            "registrationId": null,
            "vatId": null,
            "lei": null,
            "type": "ORGANISATION"
          },
          "dueDate": null,
          "amountToPay": 1,
          "amountDue": 89,
          "currency": "GBP",
          "payerDetailsResponse": {
            "id": 1,
            "institutionId": "modelo-sandbox",
            "institutionName": "Modelo Sandbox",
            "bulkAvailable": true,
            "maxBulkPayments": 50,
            "minBulkPayments": 2,
            "iban": null,
            "bic": null,
            "sortCode": "700001",
            "accountNumber": "70000001",
            "balance": -1234500801.09,
            "currency": "GBP"
          },
          "state": "COMPLETED",
          "initiationDate": "2022-02-04T11:22:05",
          "statusLastChanged": "2022-02-04T11:23:14",
          "statusLastChecked": "2022-02-04T11:23:14"
        }
      ],
      "supplier": {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "A R C Car Wash",
        "email": "ja@bra.com",
        "phone": "",
        "trusted": false,
        "paymentDetails": [
          {
            "id": null,
            "currency": null,
            "sortCode": "30-30-30",
            "accountNumber": "35353535",
            "iban": null,
            "bic": null,
            "abartn": null,
            "ifscCode": null,
            "type": "SC",
            "address": null
          }
        ],
        "externalId": "5902be62-72f9-4a04-9aa7-cb112de665ab",
        "taxResidency": null,
        "nationalId": null,
        "digitalId": null,
        "registrationId": null,
        "vatId": null,
        "lei": null,
        "type": "ORGANISATION"
      },
      "beneficiary": {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "A R C Car Wash",
        "email": "ja@bra.com",
        "phone": "",
        "trusted": false,
        "paymentDetails": [
          {
            "id": null,
            "currency": null,
            "sortCode": "30-30-30",
            "accountNumber": "35353535",
            "iban": null,
            "bic": null,
            "abartn": null,
            "ifscCode": null,
            "type": "SC",
            "address": null
          }
        ],
        "externalId": "5902be62-72f9-4a04-9aa7-cb112de665ab",
        "taxResidency": null,
        "nationalId": null,
        "digitalId": null,
        "registrationId": null,
        "vatId": null,
        "lei": null,
        "type": "ORGANISATION"
      },
      "evidences": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "evidenceType": "INVOICE",
          "storedFileFolder": "temp",
          "storedFileId": 3,
          "lineItems": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "externalId": null,
              "externalAccountID": null,
              "description": "",
              "quantity": null,
              "unitAmount": null,
              "currency": null,
              "itemCode": null,
              "accountCode": null,
              "accountName": null,
              "taxType": null,
              "taxAmount": null,
              "lineAmount": null,
              "discountRate": null,
              "discountAmount": null,
              "totalAmount": null,
              "subtotalAmount": null
            }
          ],
          "currency": "GBP",
          "total": 102,
          "subtotal": 100,
          "taxAmount": null,
          "issueDate": "2022-01-31",
          "purchaseOrderNumber": null,
          "purchaseDeliveryDate": null,
          "purchaseExpectedDeliveryDate": null,
          "purchasePaymentDueDate": null,
          "invoiceReference": "",
          "invoiceDueDate": null,
          "deliveryNote": null,
          "deliveryDate": null,
          "transactionClearedOnDate": null,
          "transactionDescription": null,
          "payrollSource": null,
          "payrollReference": null
        },
        {
          "id": 1002,
          "evidenceType": "PAYMENT_TRANSACTION",
          "storedFileFolder": null,
          "storedFileId": null,
          "lineItems": [],
          "currency": "GBP",
          "total": 1,
          "subtotal": null,
          "taxAmount": null,
          "issueDate": null,
          "purchaseOrderNumber": null,
          "purchaseDeliveryDate": null,
          "purchaseExpectedDeliveryDate": null,
          "purchasePaymentDueDate": null,
          "invoiceReference": null,
          "invoiceDueDate": null,
          "deliveryNote": null,
          "deliveryDate": null,
          "transactionClearedOnDate": "2022-02-04T11:27:47",
          "transactionDescription": null,
          "payrollSource": {},
          "payrollReference": null
        },
        {
          "id": 1003,
          "evidenceType": "PAYMENT_TRANSACTION",
          "storedFileFolder": null,
          "storedFileId": null,
          "lineItems": [],
          "currency": "GBP",
          "total": 12,
          "subtotal": null,
          "taxAmount": null,
          "issueDate": null,
          "purchaseOrderNumber": null,
          "purchaseDeliveryDate": null,
          "purchaseExpectedDeliveryDate": null,
          "purchasePaymentDueDate": null,
          "invoiceReference": null,
          "invoiceDueDate": null,
          "deliveryNote": null,
          "deliveryDate": null,
          "transactionClearedOnDate": "2022-02-04T14:08:05",
          "transactionDescription": null,
          "payrollSource": null,
          "payrollReference": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "payments": [
        {
          "id": 16,
          "evidenceId": 2,
          "purpose": "INVOICE",
          "reference": "sdfaasdfasdf",
          "beneficiary": {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "A R C Car Wash",
            "email": "ja@bra.com",
            "phone": "",
            "trusted": false,
            "paymentDetails": [
              {
                "id": null,
                "currency": null,
                "sortCode": "30-30-30",
                "accountNumber": "35353535",
                "iban": null,
                "bic": null,
                "abartn": null,
                "ifscCode": null,
                "type": "SC",
                "address": null
              }
            ],
            "externalId": "5902be62-72f9-4a04-9aa7-cb112de665ab",
            "taxResidency": null,
            "nationalId": null,
            "digitalId": null,
            "registrationId": null,
            "vatId": null,
            "lei": null,
            "type": "ORGANISATION"
          },
          "dueDate": null,
          "amountToPay": 12,
          "amountDue": 89,
          "currency": "GBP",
          "payerDetailsResponse": {
            "id": 1,
            "institutionId": "modelo-sandbox",
            "institutionName": "Modelo Sandbox",
            "bulkAvailable": true,
            "maxBulkPayments": 50,
            "minBulkPayments": 2,
            "iban": null,
            "bic": null,
            "sortCode": "700001",
            "accountNumber": "70000001",
            "balance": -1234500801.09,
            "currency": "GBP"
          },
          "state": "COMPLETED",
          "initiationDate": "2022-02-04T14:06:23",
          "statusLastChanged": "2022-02-04T14:08:05",
          "statusLastChecked": "2022-02-04T14:08:05"
        },
        {
          "id": 17,
          "evidenceId": 2,
          "purpose": "INVOICE",
          "reference": "asdfasqwerqwer",
          "beneficiary": {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "A R C Car Wash",
            "email": "ja@bra.com",
            "phone": "",
            "trusted": false,
            "paymentDetails": [
              {
                "id": null,
                "currency": null,
                "sortCode": "30-30-30",
                "accountNumber": "35353535",
                "iban": null,
                "bic": null,
                "abartn": null,
                "ifscCode": null,
                "type": "SC",
                "address": null
              }
            ],
            "externalId": "5902be62-72f9-4a04-9aa7-cb112de665ab",
            "taxResidency": null,
            "nationalId": null,
            "digitalId": null,
            "registrationId": null,
            "vatId": null,
            "lei": null,
            "type": "ORGANISATION"
          },
          "dueDate": null,
          "amountToPay": 1,
          "amountDue": 89,
          "currency": "GBP",
          "payerDetailsResponse": {
            "id": 1,
            "institutionId": "modelo-sandbox",
            "institutionName": "Modelo Sandbox",
            "bulkAvailable": true,
            "maxBulkPayments": 50,
            "minBulkPayments": 2,
            "iban": null,
            "bic": null,
            "sortCode": "700001",
            "accountNumber": "70000001",
            "balance": -1234500801.09,
            "currency": "GBP"
          },
          "state": "COMPLETED",
          "initiationDate": "2022-02-04T11:26:30",
          "statusLastChanged": "2022-02-04T11:27:47",
          "statusLastChecked": "2022-02-04T11:27:47"
        },
        {
          "id": 18,
          "evidenceId": 2,
          "purpose": "INVOICE",
          "reference": "petyavasyakatya",
          "beneficiary": {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "A R C Car Wash",
            "email": "ja@bra.com",
            "phone": "",
            "trusted": false,
            "paymentDetails": [
              {
                "id": null,
                "currency": null,
                "sortCode": "30-30-30",
                "accountNumber": "35353535",
                "iban": null,
                "bic": null,
                "abartn": null,
                "ifscCode": null,
                "type": "SC",
                "address": null
              }
            ],
            "externalId": "5902be62-72f9-4a04-9aa7-cb112de665ab",
            "taxResidency": null,
            "nationalId": null,
            "digitalId": null,
            "registrationId": null,
            "vatId": null,
            "lei": null,
            "type": "ORGANISATION"
          },
          "dueDate": null,
          "amountToPay": 1,
          "amountDue": 89,
          "currency": "GBP",
          "payerDetailsResponse": {
            "id": 1,
            "institutionId": "modelo-sandbox",
            "institutionName": "Modelo Sandbox",
            "bulkAvailable": true,
            "maxBulkPayments": 50,
            "minBulkPayments": 2,
            "iban": null,
            "bic": null,
            "sortCode": "700001",
            "accountNumber": "70000001",
            "balance": -1234500801.09,
            "currency": "GBP"
          },
          "state": "COMPLETED",
          "initiationDate": "2022-02-04T11:22:05",
          "statusLastChanged": "2022-02-04T11:23:14",
          "statusLastChecked": "2022-02-04T11:23:14"
        }
      ],
      "supplier": {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "A R C Car Wash",
        "email": "ja@bra.com",
        "phone": "",
        "trusted": false,
        "paymentDetails": [
          {
            "id": null,
            "currency": null,
            "sortCode": "30-30-30",
            "accountNumber": "35353535",
            "iban": null,
            "bic": null,
            "abartn": null,
            "ifscCode": null,
            "type": "SC",
            "address": null
          }
        ],
        "externalId": "5902be62-72f9-4a04-9aa7-cb112de665ab",
        "taxResidency": null,
        "nationalId": null,
        "digitalId": null,
        "registrationId": null,
        "vatId": null,
        "lei": null,
        "type": "ORGANISATION"
      },
      "beneficiary": {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "A R C Car Wash",
        "email": "ja@bra.com",
        "phone": "",
        "trusted": false,
        "paymentDetails": [
          {
            "id": null,
            "currency": null,
            "sortCode": "30-30-30",
            "accountNumber": "35353535",
            "iban": null,
            "bic": null,
            "abartn": null,
            "ifscCode": null,
            "type": "SC",
            "address": null
          }
        ],
        "externalId": "5902be62-72f9-4a04-9aa7-cb112de665ab",
        "taxResidency": null,
        "nationalId": null,
        "digitalId": null,
        "registrationId": null,
        "vatId": null,
        "lei": null,
        "type": "ORGANISATION"
      },
      "evidences": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "evidenceType": "INVOICE",
          "storedFileFolder": "temp",
          "storedFileId": 3,
          "lineItems": [
            {
              "id": 2,
              "externalId": null,
              "externalAccountID": null,
              "description": "",
              "quantity": null,
              "unitAmount": null,
              "currency": null,
              "itemCode": null,
              "accountCode": null,
              "accountName": null,
              "taxType": null,
              "taxAmount": null,
              "lineAmount": null,
              "discountRate": null,
              "discountAmount": null,
              "totalAmount": null,
              "subtotalAmount": null
            }
          ],
          "currency": "GBP",
          "total": 102,
          "subtotal": 100,
          "taxAmount": null,
          "issueDate": "2022-01-31",
          "purchaseOrderNumber": null,
          "purchaseDeliveryDate": null,
          "purchaseExpectedDeliveryDate": null,
          "purchasePaymentDueDate": null,
          "invoiceReference": "",
          "invoiceDueDate": null,
          "deliveryNote": null,
          "deliveryDate": null,
          "transactionClearedOnDate": null,
          "transactionDescription": null,
          "payrollSource": null,
          "payrollReference": null
        },
        {
          "id": 1012,
          "evidenceType": "PAYMENT_TRANSACTION",
          "storedFileFolder": null,
          "storedFileId": null,
          "lineItems": [],
          "currency": "GBP",
          "total": 1,
          "subtotal": null,
          "taxAmount": null,
          "issueDate": null,
          "purchaseOrderNumber": null,
          "purchaseDeliveryDate": null,
          "purchaseExpectedDeliveryDate": null,
          "purchasePaymentDueDate": null,
          "invoiceReference": null,
          "invoiceDueDate": null,
          "deliveryNote": null,
          "deliveryDate": null,
          "transactionClearedOnDate": "2022-02-04T11:27:47",
          "transactionDescription": null,
          "payrollSource": {},
          "payrollReference": null
        },
        {
          "id": 1013,
          "evidenceType": "PAYMENT_TRANSACTION",
          "storedFileFolder": null,
          "storedFileId": null,
          "lineItems": [],
          "currency": "GBP",
          "total": 12,
          "subtotal": null,
          "taxAmount": null,
          "issueDate": null,
          "purchaseOrderNumber": null,
          "purchaseDeliveryDate": null,
          "purchaseExpectedDeliveryDate": null,
          "purchasePaymentDueDate": null,
          "invoiceReference": null,
          "invoiceDueDate": null,
          "deliveryNote": null,
          "deliveryDate": null,
          "transactionClearedOnDate": "2022-02-04T14:08:05",
          "transactionDescription": null,
          "payrollSource": null,
          "payrollReference": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "pageable": {
    "sort": {
      "empty": true,
      "sorted": false,
      "unsorted": true
    },
    "offset": 0,
    "pageNumber": 0,
    "pageSize": 10,
    "paged": true,
    "unpaged": false
  },
  "last": true,
  "totalPages": 1,
  "totalElements": 2,
  "size": 10,
  "number": 0,
  "sort": {
    "empty": true,
    "sorted": false,
    "unsorted": true
  },
  "first": true,
  "numberOfElements": 10,
  "empty": false
}
```

but this what i get:-

[image]

so a lot of properties are missing such as the "PaymentDetails".. so how i can build the responses objects inside the custom connector for our JSON sample?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`paymentDetails` contains many nested fields. if you nested those fields in `paymentDetails` as a JSON object, it would work automatically.

Change this:

```
"paymentDetails": [
          {
            "id": null,
            "currency": null,
            "sortCode": "30-30-30",
            "accountNumber": "35353535",
            "iban": null,
            "bic": null,
            "abartn": null,
            "ifscCode": null,
            "type": "SC",
            "address": null
          }
        ]
```

to:

```
"paymentDetails": {
            "id": null,
            "currency": null,
            "sortCode": "30-30-30",
            "accountNumber": "35353535",
            "iban": null,
            "bic": null,
            "abartn": null,
            "ifscCode": null,
            "type": "SC",
            "address": null
          }
```